# Android Studio crashes - no project

Tags: android-studio, crash, project

my PC crashes and I have to reboot my PC

When I start Android Studio no Project appears -
even when I use Open Project

error message was "Content is not allowed in Prolog file ..."
but error message didn't appear any more

Any help???

Comment: please describe the changes you made on your last project,

Answer (score 0):

Found it :D

Just run the Project - then an error appears 
after the Crash a file seems corrupt - put the missing lines- and it works
and with ALT+1 I have Access to Project window - all files are there

Good Lord - it works really ;)